# Laravel: how does a queue job work?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, integration-testing, laravel-5.5

I'm using Larevel 5.5's built-in Redis queue. While I was writing a test queuing a payload, I noticed that the testing does not recognize the default queue name I have assigned in `queue.php`:

```
'connections' => [
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'tickets', 
    ]
```

I'm inserting a payload to the queue like this: `Job::dispacth($payload)`. It's working as intended in the actual non-test code.

My testing code:

```
public function testTicketQueue()
{
    Queue::fake();
    $payload = ['this is a ticket'];
    TicketProcessor::dispatch($payload)
        ->onQueue('tickets') // Fails without this
        ;
    Queue::assertPushedOn('tickets', TicketProcessor::class);
}
```

1. Why isn't this sending the payload to `tickets` queue? I have to explicitly assign a queue name for the testing. i.e. `->onQueue('tickets')`. If it's ignoring it intentionally, where can I find reference to such behavior?
2. I ended up tracing back `dispatch()` to see why #1 was so, but I only came to find that it is a weird (see #3) instantiation of the class `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch` like below:

   ```
   // Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable
   public static function dispatch()
   {
       return new PendingDispatch(new static(...func_get_args()));
   }

   // Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch
   public function __construct($job)
   {
       $this->job = $job;
   }
   ```

   How does `dispatch` insert the payload into the queue? Is event-based, magic, or?
3. What is `new PendingDispatch(new static(...func_get_args()));` exactly doing? Specifically, I'm not sure know what `new static` is doing as the constructor's argument. `PendingDispatch`'s constructor doesn't even take multiple arguments.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @btl Laravel has its own wrapper but seems like it uses PHPUnit underneath.

Comment: Right, I didn't see the PHPUnit tag, just the integration-testing. I'll post some information for you.

Comment: Check the phpunit.xml to see which que driver is running.  Probably not redis.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, when unit testing you don't use the actual queue implementation, instead you use Laravel facades `fake` method (akin to a Mock). Facades such as Event, Queue, Bus, Notification, etc. all provide access to a `::fake()` static method as a convenience wrapper for mocking your application's implementation.

The `dispatch` helper, as you see, simply wraps creating a `PendingDispatch` instance. The `Dispatchable` trait is where it's defined. The queue works by serializing the class passed to it, so any publicly defined properties are automatically made available within the queue.

`new static` is referencing the class of the job you're pushing to the queue. Basically, create a new instance of myself with all the arguments passed to the `dispatch` helper.

With PHP, you don't need to provide a method signature, you can define a method like:

```
public function myMethod()
```

and call it like

```
$obj->myMethod($a, $b, $c, $d)
```

That's what `func_get_args()` is doing, it's getting the all the arguments passed into the method being called. That's the magic. In the example above, `func_get_args()` would return an array `[$a, $b, $c, $d]`.

Comment: `1`: Updated my post with my testing code, which uses `fake` from the official doc. Don't I need the actual queue implementation in there like that after `Queue:fake()`? `assertPushedOn` fails otherwise and doc is unclear.

Comment: `2`/`3`: What I still don't get is the part where creating an instance of `PendingDispatch` inserts the payload to the queue. I understand now that it creates a `PendingDispatch` with a `job` property of my assignment using `new static`. But where is the followup where you actual serialize and insert this into the queue?